# Vuejs Animate.css not working

Tags: css, vue.js, css-transitions, vuejs2, animate.css

Relatively beginner in Vuejs. I am using the Animate.css library for a transition that I want.

Its basically a 4 and 8 column layout when not scrolling , which turns to 1 and 11 when I am scrolling.

It is working fine without the transition , but the overall effect is not pleasurable to the eyes.

[This is the URL , that I am using as inspiration](http://pogon.co/)

```
    <div class="column is-4 is-hidden-touch" v-show="! isScroll">
      <navcomponent :navScroll = "isScroll"></navcomponent>
    </div>

    <div class="column is-8" v-show=" ! isScroll">
      <maincontent></maincontent>
    </div>

    <transition enter-active-class="animated fadeIn" leave-active-class="animated fadeOut" mode="out-in">
      <div class="column is-1 is-hidden-touch" v-show="isScroll">
       <navcomponent :navScroll = "isScroll"></navcomponent>
      </div>

    </transition>

  <transition enter-active-class="animated fadeIn" leave-active-class="animated fadeOut" mode="out-in">

    <div class="column is-11" v-show=" isScroll">
      <maincontent></maincontent>
    </div>
  </transition>
```

Can anybody please provide pointers what I am doing wrong ?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The approach looks good to me. You can always start with a [jsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/z11fe07p/2240/)
and go from there.

```
<transition enter-active-class="animated fadeIn" leave-active-class="animated fadeOut" mode="out-in">
 <div v-if="showWhenCondition">
 </div>
</transition>
```

A transition and tag with `v-if` or `v-show` should be indeed sufficient. Can you detail more what actually happens? Any errors in console?

Comment: No errors just no effect of transition.
Problem is , I have to show the div either 4 columns or 1 column

Comment: Maybe have a basic jsfiddle with simple divs and columns like in your code

Comment: Thanks mate. Any other CSS library that has subtle transitions and plays well with Vuejs

Comment: I guess any css library which has classes. You can give vuejs transition's some classes for different transition states (eg. enter-active-class) and as long as it's a valid animation it will work

Answer (score 5):

Try this approach and you will get the result.

One has to attach `animate__animated` `animate__(animation name)` with the `transition` tag only then the specified animation would perform.

```
<transition appear enter-active-class="animate__animated animate__bounce" leave- 
    active-class="animate__animated animate__jello" mode="out-in">
    <div class="alert alert-info" v-if="show">This is some info</div>  
</transition>
```

Comment: This worked for me!

Answer (score 0):

Really stupid of me

By mistake I added the animate.css file in the index.html of another project and not the current one.

However , I am not liking the final result.

Do we have any other CSS transitions library that works well with Vuejs ? I  dont want to use Javascript hooks for tranitions coz frankly I am at a beginner level.

Something more subtle and easy on the eyes , not disturbing the flow of reading.

Comment: I'm late with this, but have a look at [wicked css](http://kristofferandreasen.github.io/wickedCSS/#).